# Deploy UDF Function on BigQuery using DBT

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

Imagine I want to deploy the following [JS function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure) to BigQuery.

I tried to wrap the SQL between macro tags and do `dbt run`, but it didn't deploy.

```
{% macro hello() %}

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
{{target.schema}}.hello(mean FLOAT64, std FLOAT64, x FLOAT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js
AS """
  return lib.hello(mean, std, x);
"""
OPTIONS (
    library=["gs://bucket/path/to/lib.js"]
);

{% endmacro %}
```

How can I do that ?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you calling this macro anywhere? This (https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/using-dbt-to-manage-user-defined-functions/18) might be out of date, but it looks like you can add a `on-run-start:` hook to your `dbt_project.yml` to call your macro.

Comment: Yes it just needed to be used in a model. Thanks. I am a beginner with dbt.

Comment: Another option is to just create the function in the BQ interface and refer to it in your dbt models.  If the function is unlikely to change, this might be acceptable.  Of course, if your dbt project is in version control, then this component woudn't be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `test.sql` model to be able to do `dbt run`.
Also, be sure to have the `on-run-start:` section filled out in `dbt_project.yml`

```sql
SELECT {{target.schema}}.hello(1.0, 1.0, 0.3) value
```

Unfortunately, a function can't be deployed just by itself.

Comment: what if you want to create the UDF in customer schema rather target. Do you know how do you refer? 
like `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION {{custom.schema}}.hello ...`